# how to use customed authentication with email/mobilephone & password?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

How to custom the default authentication method-username/password in WSO2 Identity Server 5.7.0? i.e. use password plus any of mobile/email/username to authentication an end user and provide the user an JWT token as response.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following[1][2] as per your requirement you can use basic(username/password) as authentication step 1 and SMS OTP or email OTP as step 2. Following examples are based on SAML but as you need to get JWT token as a responce you need to register an OIDC application as a service provider.[3][4]

[1].https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Email+OTP#ConfiguringEmailOTP-ConfigureWSO2ISastheemailOTPprovider

[2].https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+Multi-factor+Authentication+using+SMSOTP

[3].https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+OAuth2-OpenID+Connect+Single-Sign-On

[4].https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Try+Authorization+Code+Grant